# how to categorise the given set of datetime in C#

Tags: datetime, time, time-format

I have a list of datetime values and i need to group them into hours base.
something like

[image]

Comment: Make an attempt, and post the code with your question. What have you tried to do so far? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You can use linq:

```
        var times = new List<DateTime>();

        var groups = times.GroupBy(date => (baseTime - date).TotalHours);

        foreach (var @group in groups)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("hours: " + group.Key);
            foreach (var dateTime in group)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(dateTime);
            }
        }
```

`baseTime` is the time from where you want to start off

Comment: What is the significance of @? I've never seen that.

Comment: by that you can use a keyword as variable name, eg @if. Not superuseful, but still interesting to know :)

Comment: basetime will be the lowset time in the given list of times

Comment: @user774217: I think what you want is that basetime is the current date/time, where the hour is rounded up, eg 13:51 becomes 14:00

Answer (score 0):

You can convert Your time formats in 100 conversion

```
select convert(varchar, GetDate(), 100) as '100 Conversion'
```

Possible Result : Aug 27 2013  6:13PM
Use string manipulation like substring to retrieve the number 6 and PM

Do some Logic to sort the retrieve Data.

after that your problem is done,
Hope this Helps Thanks.